# How to convert JPanel into JFrame for a Bouncing Ball?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paint

I have obtained from somewhere else a Java Swing code for a bouncing Ball. The code uses a class "Ball" which extends a `JPanel`.

**Can Anyone help me converting this code to extends `JFrame` instead.**

I want to do that so I could be able to call it from another frame class. 
Here is the code:

```
public class Ball extends JPanel{ 
    int x=0, y=0;
    int angleX = 1, angleY = 1;

    public void move(){
        if (x + angleX <0) {
            angleX =1;
        } else if (x + angleX >getWidth()-50){
            angleX =-1;
        } else if (y + angleY <0) {
            angleY =1;
        } else if (y + angleY >getHeight()-50){
            angleY =-1;
        }
        x = x + angleX;
        y = y + angleY;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame jfrm= new JFrame("BounceBall");
        jfrm.setSize(400,400);
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jfrm.setVisible(true); 

        Ball bl = new Ball();
        Component add = jfrm.add(bl);

        while (true){
            bl.move();
            bl.repaint();
            try{
               Thread.sleep(10);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Can Anyone help me converting this code to extends JFrame instead."* 1) Just **add** the panel to a frame! There is absolutely no reason to extend a frame. 2) SO is for specific technical questions, whereas you seem to be trying to source a tutor. Voting to close as 'too broad'..

Comment: *"I have obtained from somewhere else a Java Swing code.."* The author of that code did not know what they were doing well enough to know they were overriding the wrong paint method, so the best advice we could offer is to put it back where you found it, and go through the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) lesson of the Java Tutorial.

Comment: *"I want to do that so I could be able to call it from another JFrame class."* Wow! So many poor ideas in such a short question. See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: What do you mean *"call it from another JFrame class"*? As in make some sort of pop up after e.g. button press? If so, you should use JDialog, and add this panel to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just extend `JFrame` and make some constructor for `Ball` class.

- You can make an instance from `Ball` class from any other `JFrame` classes.

  - `Ball bl = new Ball();/*then call methods*/`
- Or just call `Ball`s main method in two ways:

  - `Ball.main(null);`
  - `String args[]={/*some arguments*/}; Ball.main(args)`;

Here is your `Ball` class which now extends `JFrame`

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Ball extends JFrame {

    public Ball() {
        setSize(400, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    int x = 0, y = 0;
    int angleX = 1, angleY = 1;

    public void move() {
        if (x + angleX < 0) {
            angleX = 1;
        } else if (x + angleX > getWidth() - 50) {
            angleX = -1;
        } else if (y + angleY < 0) {
            angleY = 1;
        } else if (y + angleY > getHeight() - 50) {
            angleY = -1;
        }
        x = x + angleX;
        y = y + angleY;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Ball bl = new Ball();

        while (true) {
            bl.move();
            bl.repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is encouraging bad practices by replicating the problems in the original source code. Added to that, it extends frame which, although that is what the OP asked for, is completely unnecessary.

Comment: `Anyone help me converting this code to extends JFrame instead.` i just helped, and i changed some part of original code. where i replicated the problems? to solve problem at last we must change original source code. is there another way to solve problem?

Comment: *"i just helped"* That (lack of quality of) code is not helping. *"where i replicated the problems?"* The first is mentioned in my 2nd comment. The second is using a `while (true){` loop instead of using a Swing `Timer` to trigger repaint..

Comment: @AndrewThompson i will use your advice in my next activities on `stackoverflow`. and also in my codes. thank you.